# Why is PDF file size so small?

Tags: pdf, filesize

I have a few copies of textbooks this semester on PDF. These are 1000 page computer science textbooks full of graphics. When I downloaded it, it took just a few seconds which was amazing, I thought something had gone wrong. The entire textbook was 9.7 MB. I opened it up and sure enough, the entire textbook was there, all images and everything were loaded instantly (and I have a really terrible internet connection)

I am just wondering what amazing compression technique allows you to store 1000 pages of a textbook in under 10 MB?

Here is a screenshot of the file properties, I am so baffled.
[image]

Comment: Read the textbooks and find out!

Comment: What kind of images, what resolution, how many?

Comment: Text doesn't take up much space. Adding in compression makes it even better. The killer is images. A PDF with 50 low quality images, easily run up in 50+ megabyte.

Comment: On average, each of your "1000 pages in 10MB" occupies  a whopping 10,000 bytes. You don't say anything about the size of the page, the margins, and the font size, but a typical text book only has about 3,000 characters per page. So "amazing" is not exactly the right word. (And that is *uncompressed*. Usually, the data in a PDF is compressed as well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [typical text page is between 3k and 6k](http://erikastokes.com/misc-stuff/how-many-bytes-are-in-a-page-of-text.php) tokens. So the text of your 1000 page book would fit in 6MB even without compression.

Normal compression tools can reduce plain ASCII text with something like 60-80%.

So lets say it's 75%, then you need 0.25 x 6MB = 1.5MB for the text. That leaves 8.5 MB for the pictures.

For vector based images like svg that's a lot, they are small and compress as well as text. But 8.5 MB does not leave room for a lot of embedded bitmaps.